# How to add an empty column to a Snowflake COPY INTO statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to upload a file into Snowflake that has two columns but also add an additional third empty column and a fourth column with a value of 'N' for all rows.

myfile.csv has these columns: UUID, PHONE_NUMBER

Here is my script:

```sql
create or replace table my_database.my_table (  

    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(38,0)
    ,UUID VARCHAR(50)
    ,PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(10)
    ,REGISTERED CHAR(1)
    
);

copy into dtable my_database.my_table (

     NULL as CUSTOMER_ID
    ,UUID
    ,PHONE_NUMBER
    ,’N’ REGISTERED
    
)           

from @fl_template_misc                                                                                                        
file_format = (                                                                                                        
  type = CSV                                                                                                         
  encoding = 'UTF8'                                                                                                    
  field_delimiter = '|'                                                                                                
  null_if = ('NULL','null','')                                                                                  
  field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'                                                                                   
  trim_space = true                                                                                                    
  skip_header = 1                                                                                                    
  date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY'                                                                                           
  time_format = 'HH24:MI:SS')                                                                                          
  on_error = 'ABORT_STATEMENT'                                                                                         
;
```

Here is the error snowsql gives me: syntax error line 3 at position 1 unexpected 'NULL'.

Do I need to update the null_if = ?

Answer (score 0):

To transform data within a `COPY INTO` you need to do a sub-select.

For example:

```sql
copy into home_sales(city, zip, sale_date, price)
from (
       select NULL as CUSTOMER_ID
          ,UUID
          ,PHONE_NUMBER
          ,’N’ REGISTEREDnull, SUBSTR(t.$2,4), t.$1, t.$5, t.$4 
       from @fl_template_misc t
)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = mycsvformat);
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform#transforming-csv-data